# Do bubbles get created when you move something in water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bubbles

I've seen in a lot of movies and animations of bubbles forming when something moves underwater (e.g., fish swimming). Is it theoretically possible (under any temperature, pressure circumstance possible in oceans) that bubbles could form miles underwater, just because of mere movement?

Comment: Hi! Look at this video: https://youtu.be/U-uUYCFDTrc

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Certainly, the mechanism is called *cavitation* and it works like this:

As an object moves through water, a pressure distribution gets built up around the walls of the object and depending on its shape, it is possible for pressures at some points to be lower than ambient pressure- the best example of this is on the backwards face of a rotating propeller blade.

If that propeller blade moves fast enough through the water, that "negative pressure" grows until it equals the *vapor pressure* of the water at that ambient condition and the water there explodes into vapor- in essence, it boils. As soon as those *cavitation bubbles* full of vapor form, any dissolved air in the water nearby will diffuse into the vapor bubbles and collect there. Because the pressure in the cavitation bubble is below ambient, as soon as the moving object sheds a bubble it tends to quickly collapse as the vapor inside the bubble condenses back into liquid water- but the re-dissolution process for the air in the bubble is much slower, and so after the vapor bubble is gone a tiny air-filled bubble remains.

Note that the lifetime of a cavitation bubble is measured in milliseconds, and those air remnants are far tinier than anything portrayed in a cartoon.

Comment: Re, "the lifetime of a cavitation bubble is measured in milliseconds." But then there's [_supercavitation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercavitation) in which the flow is continuous, and the vapor bubble is stable.

Comment: Is cavitation the primary mechanism? It requires relatively fast moving objects, and a lot of force.

Comment: @BillThePlatypus, yes it is, and it does require fast-moving objects.

Comment: @D.Halsey Indeed, cavitation is undesirable in boat design, because although the bubbles are small, the sharp pressure changes are hard on mechanical parts. It's *really* bad if your boat is a submarine, since cavitation is quite loud and will give your position away.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Congratulations on a great answer based on practical examples (backwards face of a rotating propeller blade).

Comment: @BobD thank you from another recovering ex-engineer

Comment: Great explanation, add a source and it's a good answer ;-)

Comment: Wow, mindlessly sourcing and siting like this is an English literature movie? Cavitation is the most certain example i can think of and no source is required what so ever. Interesting related ideas are that also, often water is often permitted by oxygen to different amounts, (nitrogen too), which may be a different phenomena related to bubbles. However it seems one central theme to a bubble is Surface tension, surface energy, adhesion and cohesion, no?

Comment: @marshal craft, let me assure you that there's nothing mindless in my posted answer and furthermore it resembles nothing in an english literature movie. If you disagree, you are free to post your own answer here. If it's better than mine I'll delete mine.

Comment: @M.Stern, my answer was based on 28 years of personal experience with vapor explosions, cavitation collapse, and outgassing as observed under a microscope. Sorry I cannot cite any references, but my employer did not allow me to publish :-(

Comment: My comment about mindless was to stern on the necessity of a source.

Answer (score 18):

Yes this is theoretically possible, and it is also observed in practice. Gases, including oxygen and carbon dioxide certainly, and probably also nitrogen, are absorbed in solution by water from the air (if oxygen were not absorbed fish would not be able to breathe underwater). Once in solution, the distribution of dissolved particles diffuses naturally through the whole body of the water, to any depth. If water is agitated into turbulent motion, then gases are ejected from solution because turbulence generates rapidly varying pressure. Gas is less soluble in liquid at lower pressure. You can also observe the effect simply by shaking a fizzy drink.

Cavitation is a similar effect, but in this case the bubble contains water vapour, and is produced because the pressure dropped to the point where water boils. Cavitation bubbles generally collapse extremely rapidly.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Cavitation is a big problem with ship propellers.

Comment: @DavidHammen, then why should an answer which explains the underlying theoretical mechanism for cavitation (even if the word was not originally mentioned) not be accepted?

Comment: As I understand it dissolved gasses are not required for cavitation. All you need is water, in which the bubbles will be entirely filled with water vapor until the collapse. The bubbles form and expand in those small windows of time and space where the local pressure is less than the vapor pressure of water at the given temperature - the same conditions that give rise to boiling. Cavitation is just boiling caused by a small temporary region of low pressure in a liquid, and the subsequent reversal of that boiling at higher pressure.

Comment: @bdsl, Re, "Cavitation is _just_..."  Everything you said there is true, but cavitation is none the less, an interesting phenomenon. The interesting bit is how those bubbles _collapse,_ and what happens as a consequence. Google for 'cavitation damage' to see some examples.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Agreed. My use of 'just' was probably inappropriate.

Comment: I don't think the answer meant to combine water being petmiated with air, and cavitation, so point about cavitation not requiring dissolved air is mute. Actually I wonder to be more precise, actually cavitation may not be technically a bubble or a stable bubble in all cases. It could be argued the cavitation bubble which is more of a hyper sonic dash expansion and collapse phenomena, it is not stable ever. A bubble seems to be stable in other cases which require a more abstracted notion of surface energy minimization between two different, 3d regions, though the chemical make up may be  ...

Comment: Technically homogeneous in aggregate. Indeed the rapidly spinning propeller is the ____ example, producing cavitation super sonic expansion and collapse (sometimes even emitting photons and sound waves), additionally producing traditional bubbles.

Comment: Additionally a jet contrail consist of water vapor, a vapor consisting of small water droplets. A droplet can be viewed as an inside out bubble however the boundary should still be the same.

Comment: Re: "Gases, including oxygen and carbon dioxide certainly, and probably also nitrogen, are absorbed in solution by water from the air (if oxygen were not absorbed fish would not be able to breathe underwater)": Of course, oxygen and carbon dioxide can also be produced underwater; it's estimated that at least half the Earth's oxygen comes from the ocean. [[link](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/ocean-oxygen.html)]

Answer (score 8):

Yes, cavitation is real, but my understanding is that fish are not cavitating very much (dolphins are known to avoid swimming fast enough to cause cavitation, because the collapsing cavitation bubbles are painful to them).

Plants, bacteria, and other forms of marine life slowly generate gases as part of their metabolic processes. Some of these gases dissolve directly, but some form small bubbles that collect on various surfaces (due to surface tension, being trapped in silt, trapped under an overhang, etc.). When a fish comes by, the sudden motion of the water knocks the bubbles loose to float upwards. In this case the motion isn't *creating* bubbles, it's *releasing* bubbles that are continuously forming in the environment.

Comment: Pistol shrimp use cavitation as a weapon

Comment: @stannius yes, but that's clearly not what the question is asking about :)

Answer (score 1):

If you move a body enough fast, in the high pressure zones water will boil -> forms bubbles
Its called cavitation.